# Use python cmd library with custom separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following stub to create a repl:

```
import cmd
class Repl(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = 'sql> '
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Repl().cmdloop()
```

And it works in a very basic sense. However, there are two things I am looking to add here:

```
Desktop david$ python client.py
sql> select 1;
*** Unknown syntax: select 1;
sql> select * FROM
*** Unknown syntax: select 1,
```

1. There are no custom commands. Everything is interpreted as SQL and so I just want one default method to handle everything, basically a `do_*`.
2. I want a `;\n` to be what executes the command. In other words, I want to be able to add newlines without executing the command, such as a normal sql shell:

```
mysql> select *
    -> from person;

0 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

How would I add these two things to a class that inherits `cmd.Cmd` ?

---

It seems perhaps the [`Cmd.default`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.default). can be used as a catch-all, such as:

```
import cmd
class Repl(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = 'sql> '
    def default(self, line):
        print (line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Repl().cmdloop()
```

```
Desktop david$ python3 client.py
sql> select 1;
--> select 1;
```

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @KevinSmeeks various ones. For now it's just to do a sample though, it's not against an actual database.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will not work, it is generic idea, with more information on what DBMS you are using I could update the answer.

You just need to connect to the database and execute the queries given. One thing to do would be to override the preloop method to open a connection to the database

```
import cmd
class Repl(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = 'sql> '

    def preloop(self):
        # store database connection here on self.dbconnection
        pass

    def default(self, line):
        # change this to what is necessary based on the connection package you use
        self.dbconnection.execute(line)
        for row in self.dbconnection.fetchall():
            print(row)
```

Comment: I'm not looking to execute anything. I'm just looking to use multiple lines in a command -- sql is just an example.

Comment: If the only function you are going to use is default and have no custom commands you could look using msg = sys.stdin.readlines(), but this requires user to use CTRL+Z to send a EOF marker